# overview map with sharpmap

Tags: sharpmap

I'm using Sharpmap to create a GIS application. I'm trying to get a small overview map on top of my map so it gives an idea what part of the map is being viewed.

Is there a simple/implemented way of doing this or do I need to add another map and interact with this map on every change?

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup another map and handle MapCenterChanged and MapZoomChanged events.